# Json array of objects inserting meta data

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to create a simple array of objects and it's printing out some meta data that I don't want. What am I doing wrong that this meta data is being returned?

```
public JsonArray makeJsonArray(CustomQueryResult result) {

    JsonArrayBuilder array = Json.createArrayBuilder();

    String [] keys = result.getKeywordTypes();
    String [][] results = result.getKeywordValues();

    for(int i = 0; i < results.length; i ++){
        array.add(Json.createObjectBuilder().add("hey", "yo").build());
    }

    return array.build();
}
```

This is what is being returned:

```
[
  {
    "hey": {
      "chars": "yo",
      "valueType": "STRING",
      "string": "yo"
    }
  }
]
```

This is what I would have expected:

```
[
  {
    "hey": "yo"
  }
]
```

Comment: I believe it's because you are calling `.build()` twice. As a result, you're building `"yo"` as JSON. Try removing the `.build()` inside your `for` loop. Notice how the code in [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArrayBuilder.html) just calls the function once.

Comment: I tried that as well and it still produces the same output.